# Pandas conditionaly swap values in two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with two columns. In some of the rows the columns are swapped. If they're swapped then column "a" will be negative. What would be the best way to check that and then swap the values of the two columns.

```
def swap(a,b):
    if a < 0:
        return b,a
    else:
        return a,b
```

Is there some way to use apply with this function to swap the two values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this ? By using `np.where`

```
ary=np.where(df.a<0,[df.b,df.a],[df.a,df.b])
pd.DataFrame({'a':ary[0],'b':ary[1]})

Out[560]: 
   a  b
0  3 -1
1  3 -1
2  8 -1
3  2  9
4  0  7
5  0  4
```

Data input :

```
df
Out[561]: 
   a  b
0 -1  3
1 -1  3
2 -1  8
3  2  9
4  0  7
5  0  4
```

***And using `apply`***

```
def swap(x):
    if x[0] < 0:
        return [x[1],x[0]]
    else:
        return [x[0],x[1]]


df.apply(swap,1)
Out[568]: 
   a  b
0  3 -1
1  3 -1
2  8 -1
3  2  9
4  0  7
5  0  4
```

Comment: Time to start a new ipython sesh... ;)

Comment: `[560]` is light weight (-:

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga going to close it :)

Answer (score 1):

Out of boredom:

```
df.values[:] = df.values[
    np.arange(len(df))[:, None],
    np.eye(2, dtype=int)[(df.a.values >= 0).astype(int)]
]

df

   a  b
0  3 -1
1  3 -1
2  8 -1
3  2  9
4  0  7
5  0  4
```